# Names bound to both the decomposed discriminated union components AND an original composed value

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I can't find documentation on this.  I need to decompose a Discriminated Union value into some of its components but I also need to use the item as a whole within the body of a function as well.

I can do `let matcher = function MyDU(_,b,_) -> b` or `let extractor MyDU(_,b,_) = b` but what if I also need the reference to the MyDU value for something like `... -> RedundantWrapper(myDU, b)`

I've tried:

```
let extractor myDU = 
    let MyDU(_,b,_) = myDU
    RedundantWrapper(myDU, b)
```

but I don't think that is the right syntax.  Perhaps I can do this some longer way, but it seems like there would be a short way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
let (Some(x) as o) = Some 1

// val o : int option = Some 1
// val x : int = 1
```

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying about `as o` - not necessary when it already has a name - but also I was interpreting it as a C# cast (incorrectly).  This is a great answer, but I think the other syntax I found is even more exactly what I was looking for so I switched it for the good of future travelers.

Comment: now that I understand the `as` better, I realize it can be used in the same places that I might use `&`.  So this really was the right answer I was looking for but I didn't recognize it at first.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I just realized that this short-hand is allowed which I think everyone here will agree is PRETTY AWESOME.

```
let extractor (myDU & MyDU(_,b,_)) = 
    RedundantWrapper(myDU, b)
```

Comment: This is clever, but arguably a hack, given that there's syntax specific to this purpose (`as`). `&` gives the impression that the first test can fail, which is false.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed it was for this purpose (not that "purpose" is critical).  [MSDN - Pattern Matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) uses it this way.  Can you explain a situation where this would not work, be less performant, type-check properly or be otherwise bad?  `as` dictates that myDU would have to be in the second operand(?) and `&` could be used for additional patterns if so desired.  Right?

Comment: It's a minor quibble (and weakly held) that `as` expresses the intent—to unconditionally bind the value to an identifier—more clearly. There are no other concerns...although I did find, curiously, that the compiled form of `&` uses an additional variable.